# Why is Google Maps replacing latitude and longitude variables with my current location?

Tags: google-maps

from a Safari web application, I am calling this link:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/hotel/@41.959816,12.802226
```

the page of Google Maps after a few redirection takes me here

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/hotel/@41.8984484,12.5051106,15z/data=!3m1!4b1
```

that is to my current location.
Is there a reason why is this happening?

Thanks
Fabio

Comment: I am aware of this, but I am requested to open a new window of Google maps, rather than build a new map within the web app. Anyway, the very first address in the new window address bar is correct, then it takes into account my current location. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the zoom level on  your query:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/hotel/@41.959816,12.802226,13z
```